# How to access /var/www/html/index.html file path through sftp on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: html, ubuntu, command-line, terminal, server

I setup a fresh install of **Ubuntu 16.04.2** on Digital Ocean. I setup a user and when I try connecting SFTP, I am not seeing the index.html file path. How do I access and setup through **sftp** so I can replace the current `index.html` file?

When I visit the IP, I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePOhO.png) screen. So the files are there.

When I connect sftp with current user, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXYCD.png) is the structure I am seeing. I am missing the `/var/www/html/index.html` file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** 
Changed the directory for the user I setup to the html folder using the following command.

```
usermod -d /var/www/html greg
```